# Are these kinds of "crossed product" studied?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra acting in a Hilbert space $H$, and let $\rho$ be a representation of a group $G$ on a Hilbert space $K$. Define $M\rtimes_\rho G$ to be a von Neumann algebra acting in the Hilbert space $H\bar\otimes K$ generated by 
$$x\otimes\rho(g), \quad x\in M, g\in G$$
Is  the von Neumann algebra $M\rtimes_\rho G$ studied?

Comment: but what is your multiplication? the trivial one leads to $M \otimes VN^*(G)$ !?

Comment: @hänsel Do you know somewhere which this kind of crossed product is studied with non trivial multiplication?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan: with $G \subset Aut(M)$ you can get a non-trivial multiplication via the usual crossed product: see Chapter X in Takesaki's book *[Theory of Operator Algebras II](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1943006)*.